# Curve Bevel very inconsistent

Tags: bevel

I've ran into a little problem while trying to create a sort of railing - i've created a plane, subdivided it and then deleted only the faces which left me with this.

[image]

Next Step was to convert this into a curve to then bevel it and have a railing - but there lies my problem. The Bevel is very inconsistent and all over the place.

[image]

Scale is 1,1,1, all transforms are applied and switching to 2D doesn't help - so after gooogling for a while i'm all out of ideas.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: a curve vertex can only be connected to 2 other vertices, not 3 or 4, therefore the problem with your topology

Comment: Thank you, but then i wonder how this guy does it ?    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmACxKsDtlk   at around 12:50 you can see it ?

Comment: see few seconds before, at 12:20, the edges are not connected

Comment: Oh, i see, thank you for pointing that out, i must have missed that. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could try a different approach, and use a [skin modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/skin.html#skin-modifier) on a mesh object for something like this.

[image]

In edit mode mark a vertex as root, select a vertex and choose *Mark Root* in the modifier. Also add a [subdivision surface modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html#subdivision-surface-modifier) to smooth the result.

[image]

---

You will likely need to scale the skin down some initially, in edit mode do this by selecting all and using <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to resize.

Comment: I will give that a try, thank you very much for showing me this approach.